# Affine variety example.

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, self-learning, affine-geometry

[image]

I know how to show the statement. But I cannot find an example (the part I underlined by a yellow pen) please help me for finding an example.

*Note:* For example, can I consider the following example; the irreducible cubic plane curve $Z(y^2 − x^3 + x)$ ?

If this true, please explain a little bit?:) thanks:)

Comment: Sure you can. Think curves...

Comment: I am thinking an example for two days.but,  I cannot really find. Please give me a hint/ suggestion :) @Mike

Comment: What are the simplest types of algebraic curves you can think of?

Comment: Well, I would consider the simplest class (except for straight lines) to be quadratic curves - which is the family I would suggest looking at. But certainly there are examples within cubic curves as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) The simplest example is with $n=r=1$: take $\mathfrak a=\langle X_1(X_1-1)\rangle \subset k[X_1]$.
Then $Z(\mathfrak a)=\{0,1\}$ has two irreducible  components $\{0\}, \{1\}$ each of dimension $n-r=1-1=0$.

b) If that was too degenerate for your taste, the next simplest example is with $n=2,r=1$ and  $\mathfrak a=\langle X_1X_2\rangle \subset k[X_1,X_2]$.
Then $Z(\mathfrak a)=Z(X_1)\cup Z(X_2)$   has two irreducible components $Z(X_1), Z(X_2)$, each of dimension $n-r=2-1=1$.